# Pronoun first, then name?

Tags: usage

When you use propositional phrases or conjunctive phrases, do you use a pronoun that matches your subject prior to mentioning the actual subject?

> I don't think you'll need **her** number, but **Jennifer's** number is x.

> I don't think you'll need **Jennifer's** number, but **her** number is x.

> Although **she** is late, I think **Jennifer** will be here any minute now.

> Although **Jennifer** is late, I think **she** will be here any minute now.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/109843/#comment222847_109848

Comment: See particularly John Lawler's *Comments* in snailboat's link. If you like technical terms, what you're askign about is [*cataphora*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cataphora).

Answer (score 4):

In your first two examples, the repetition of the word number makes me think you are talking about two different people.

> As for Susan, I don't think you'll need her number. But Jennifer's number is 555-5555.

I think the meaning you want would be conveyed better without mentioning the subject twice:

> I don't think you'll need her number, but it's 555-5555.

or

> I don't think you'll need Jennifer's number, but it's 555-5555.

Your second two examples are both standard, and have identical meanings.

Comment: Although I agree that your reading is possible (or even likely), I think the first two sentences are ambiguous.  In either case, if you stress *need* and not *her* or *Jennifer*, the contrastive reading disappears.  Still, I think this is a useful answer, so I'm going to vote it up.

Comment: @snailboat, you're right. I think OP's use of bold to emphasize the words s/he was asking about made me read it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a pronoun prior to mentioning its subject (and you should always use a pronoun matching the subject).

Some other examples:

> If you need *it*, Jennifer's number is 555-1212.
>
> If you need to call *her*, Jennifer is available after 9 am.
>
> An hour after I started looking for *him*, I found John in the mall cafe.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the OP's question. Jess isn't asking whether to use a pronoun matching the subject, but whether the pronoun should be mentioned before the subject.

Comment: @Stephan, hopefully the edit makes the answer more directly applicable.